# Semantic UI: right aligned/floated button

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

How do I align a button correctly using Semantic-UI at the right? I've tried things like:

```
            <div class="ui mini labeled input">
                <div class="ui label">Description</div>
                <input placeholder="Privat" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="ui floated right red mini button">
                Remove
            </div>
            <br />
```

But the button is always below the input field. Could you explain (in addition to the correct solution) why this happens? Do I have to use a grid?

Second question beside this:

Two labeled inputs like

```
            <div class="ui mini labeled input">
                <div class="ui label">description</div>
                <input placeholder="Privat" type="text">
            </div><br/>
            <div class="ui mini labeled input">
                <div class="ui label">another description</div>
                <input placeholder="Privat" type="text">
            </div>
```

Do not have the same length. Neither the gray label nor the total input field. Is this alignable?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4p6d7x86/1/) test

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements are `inline-flex` (`inline-block`), that's why you have to break the lines manually using `<br />`.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/4p6d7x86/2/

Comment: Thanks :) I have a weird problem: My elements are `display: table` not `inline-flex`. Compared class of jsfiddle vs. my real code: `.ui.labeled.input`. Do you have an idea?

Comment: In this case change the child element's `display` to `table-cell`.

Comment: Seems like I wasn't using the current SemanticUI version. After updating it, everything is working like expected.