# How to use floated style in <figure> tags when using semantic-ui

Tags: css, semantic-ui

Say I want my web page display things like [this](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/image.html#floated), but I want to use `<figure>` tag.
The problem is that simply attach the style on to the `<figure>` is not a perfect way.
For example, if add `circular`, then both of the `<img>` and `<figcaption>` will be "circulared".

```html
<figure class="ui small right floated image circular">
    <img src="/img/here.jpg">
    <figcaption><a href="">Caption here...</a></figcaption>
</figure>
```

[caption of the picture is "circulared" too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh1yx.png)

Can semantic-ui work like this:

```html
<figure class="ui right floated">
    <img class="image small circular"> 
    <figcaption class="something else">
```

kind like inheritance?

Comment: You want to use figure tag only or also looking for any solution using normal div and image?

Comment: `figure` tag would be the best, but what's your opinion on this problem? Can normal `div` and `image` do this?

Comment: I have answered with a codepen example I hope it will help you solve your problem let me know

Comment: hey @funk1d did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963655/semantic-ui-floats).

## CSS

```html
<style>
    [class*="left floated"] {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0.25em;
    }

    [class*="right floated"] {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 0.25em;
    }

    figcaption[class*="centered"] {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

Then, if you want to right float or left float the whole `<figure>`, just add it to the class, like below:

```html
<figure class="right floated">
    <img class="ui small bordered centered circular image" src="image.png">
    <figcaption class="centered">
        Caption here...
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

If you want the whole `<figure>` be centered, just leave the `<figure>` class blank, and the browser will render it to "center float" by default. But the `centered` in `<img>` is still necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will solve your problem with img tag and div let me know if any doubt check this code pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OdqKLy

### html

```
<div class="card">
   <div>
     <img class="ui image circular" src="https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-500kb.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <a href="">Caption here...</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.card {
  width: 180px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```